# spinner in android eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

I changed the background colour of the spinner.After changing the bg colour the down arrow in the spinner is not visible.Is there any ways to visible that arrow after changing the colour.

```
android:background="#ffff00"
```

Thanks for any help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think so. You need to choose your background color in such a way that is visible. Another but a longer option is to make a custom spinner by extending Spinner and overriding its `onDraw()`.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that is why while customizing a spinner we use 9patch images.
Do check this, 
http://www.mokasocial.com/2011/03/easily-create-a-default-custom-styled-spinner-android/

It would get you started on customizing android apps

Happy coding mate
:)